# The meaning of 'otherwise' in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I have read this sentences and wonder what and why there is an "otherwise" in this sentence. And what is actual meaning of this, do I have responsible in this case?

> You shall not **otherwise** be responsible for the damage of the good.

I am not native English speaker.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ELU! Please post a context for this sentence. The meaning will depend on the context that surrounds it. Also, what research have you done before posting?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/otherwise), adverb definition #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *otherwise* here means *except for some situation.* So, the sentence means:

> You are not responsible for the damage of the good, except for some situation [which must have just been mentioned in a previous sentence].

For example, I could say:

> If you intentionally broke the glass, then you are responsible. But, you are not otherwise responsible for the damage to the glass.

So, you would be responsible for the damage to the glass if you broke it intentionally. In all other situations, you would not be responsible.